# How to make a Rails engine expose a file to the Rails App Root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I know inside my Rails engine I can create an `app/controllers/blah_controller.rb` file and that controller will be accessible from my Rails app just like it was defined in the Rails app itself.

If I want the engine to expose a file into the root of the Rails application, where do I put that in the Rails engine?  A basic gem would have a structure like:

```
my_engine
  |_bin
  |_lib
  .gitignore
  my_engine.gempspec
  Gemfile
  Rakefile
  README.md
```

Do I just add `the_file.rb` to root of the gem?  If so, how does Rails know to include it and not the other files in the gem root?

```
my_engine
  |_bin
  |_lib
  .gitignore
  my_engine.gempspec
  Gemfile
  Rakefile
  README.md 
  the_file.rb    # I want this file to be present in the Rails app root.
```

Comment: Have a look at the last section: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tips-for-writing-your-own-rails-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No` Rails won't know how to load root path files.

The part of rails you are looking for is a railtie engine: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html

I hope you mounted the engine to an application so you can debug. Within your app that has an engine, you can check eager loaded paths:

```
MyEngine::Engine.config.eager_load_paths
```

which returns an array of all loaded paths.

All you need to do is: to configure Engine to load the root path:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    config.eager_load_paths << File.expand_path('../../..', __FILE__)
  end
end
```

Then create a dummy initializer in the Rails app, that requires your engine root file:

```
# /config/initializers/my_engine_dummy.rb
require 'your_engine_root_file.rb'
```

Place some methods inside `your_engine_root_file.rb`

```
p 'Welcome to my engine`
```

load rails console from your rails application and see the beautiful message

*Assumption:*

I assumed that you are using MyEngine as the namespace for the engine.

*Suggestion:*

Not to do that :) As many know that name collapse is a common thing in software development. So you might want to isolate your engine files behind the namespace.

Hope that helps